# spring oauth2 configuration - Invalid property 'autoApproveScopes'

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am facing error in configuring the Ouath2.Its giving **`BeanCreationException`**.

Below is the stacktrace,please help me out in solving this.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientDetails': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.BaseClientDetails] while setting bean property 'clientDetailsStore' with key [the_client]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'autoApproveScopes' of bean class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.BaseClientDetails]: Bean property 'autoApproveScopes' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:379) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:162) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 98 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'autoApproveScopes' of bean class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.BaseClientDetails]: Bean property 'autoApproveScopes' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1423) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 110 more
**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'autoApproveScopes' of bean class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.BaseClientDetails]: Bean property 'autoApproveScopes' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?**
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1042) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:902) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 114 more
```

Comment: Can somebody help me for the above error ?

Comment: Could you share your authorisation server config? We can't really do a lot just from a stack trace!

Comment: @Prasanna Kumar, I've voted to reject your proposed edit in the review: I think that formatting the stack trace is helpful, but it doesn't make this question usable for Stack Overflow. For that, OP must create an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to really be of any help here.